# How to share individual images from the library on google plus with some description?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus, share

I'm using angularJS to develop my application which has many e-cards and each has listed with thumbnails on my home page. From the home page user can share on various social media.

Right now I have shared using https://plus.google.com/share?url= but this is not sufficient for me as it pick-up loading image as image reference and I don't want to share that (Obviously), I would like to share the image user has selected along with the description.

Is there any stream api in google for javascript that will help me for the dynamic content sharing?

Still I wonder How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive). I think they will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add special meta tags to your page

```
<meta itemprop="name" content=""/>
<meta itemprop="description" content=""/>
<meta itemprop="image" content=""/>
```

Where image is url that should be your preview image.

You can specify sharing options for other networks as well

Twitter:

```
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
```

Facebook: (image better be 256x256 png or jpg)

```
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
```

Windows 8 menu links:

```
<meta name="application-name" content=""/> 
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content=""/>
```